# How can I support in-browser display of a PDF file in Internet Explorer 64-bit

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, adobe, browser

Adobe does not seem to support the display of PDFs in the browser when using the 64-bit version of Internet Explorer. Once a pdf link is clicked the 64-bit Internet Explorer will always span a new Adobe window to display the pdf. The 32-bit Internet Explorer will display the pdf embedded in the browser itself.

I noticed this issue when using the WebBrowser control in a 64-bit complied WinForms .NET application. I don't believe it's possible to use the 32-bit WebBrowser control in the 64-bit application so I am looking for some solutions to this problem even if it requires the use of a third party plug-in.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Just found this piece of information in SO. "Internet Explorer 64bit can run only 64bit plugins. The Adobe PDF plugin is 32bit and it cannot run in 64bit IE". So, what I'm really looking for here is some creative alternative?

Comment: Could you use a different browser engine? WebKit can handle PDFs just fine afaik

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, unfortunately, using a different browser engine is not an option :-(

Comment: Just set your project's Platform target to x86.

Comment: I need to keep my platform target as 64-bit.

Comment: I added `winforms` to your list of tags, since it is one of the primary technologies in question.

Comment: There are 3rd party PDF readers writen in .NET that may work for you.

Comment: Any help with finally solving this would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you platform target needs to be x64, and your need to use an x64-incompatible feature, then clearly you have an issue.  You're going to have to compromise on one side or the other.

Alternatively, you could look into opening a separate process for the PDF viewer and setting the parent window of the newly spawned process' window to your container control.  This will have the effect of "embedding" the window within your control.  You can then forcefully remove the border and maximize it.  Windows API, to the rescue!  Check out [Sumatra PDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html) if you decide to go this route, which you can probably distribute without any trouble.

Comment: Hi @Zenexer, Are there any articles you can link to?  Given my lack of experience w/ Win API and the potential pitfalls (bellow) I’d be more inclined to try it with expert guidance. Based on the comments from Hans Passant on this post: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152449/32-bit-activex-control-in-a-64-bit-net-app) it sounds like this may not be a practical solution.  In my case I need to embed adobe acrobat (which is a common topic of discussion with no solutions.)  The plumbing to accomplish an out-of process solution does not sound promising.

Comment: @dyslexicanaboko Running it in a separate process is quite impractical.  However, seeing as you cannot have a process running both 32-bit and 64-bit code, it's your only option until Adobe is a bit more up-to-date.  It's also a technique that I've done successfully in similar situations, so it's definitely possible.  Best part is, you can forego the web browser control altogether.  You're also dealing with an entire application, not an ActiveX control, which actually makes this technique easier.