# Check if there is any kind of PDF Reader installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf

I have a `Help` function in my `Application`, that consists of one `webbrowser control`. That `webbrowser control` gets filled with a `.pdf file`, the source for that `.pdf file` is our own website.

The problem is, that not everyone will have a `PDF Reader` installed on their machine, so I want to check whether one is installed: Yes or No. I searched the internet and I mostly saw that users on Stackoverflow where wanting to check if `Adobe Reader` was installed, that is not what I want. I need to know IF there is a `PDF Reader` somewhere installed on the machine.

I did find the following code, that can possibly help me:

```
public void CheckPdfReaderAvailable()      
{      
    RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(".pdf");      
    Assert.IsNotNull(key);      
}
```

As I look at the above code, my thoughts are that the code checks if the `registry` does know the `.pdf format`, but I'am not sure.

Can somebody tell me how to use the code above or provide me an example, about how I should take down this problem?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

The following answer helped my out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/774482/1661209

Another way to solve this problem, is to add a pdf reader lite to the prerequisites and make the users install that first, you don't have to check for a pdf Reader, because you know one is installed then, if it isn't you could say it is the mistake of the user that they can't use the help function, because you offered them a way to install the pdf reader easily using the published project.

Comment: Why not have HTML in a WebBrowser control? Why not just throw the PDF at the user and let them deal with it? What do you do if they don't have a PDF viewer installed?

Comment: That is my problem here, I want to check if a user has a PDF viewer installed: Yes or No, if not I will provide them a download link, so they can still make use of my help function.

Comment: Check this answer maybe it can help you or open a path for you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086973/how-can-i-programmatically-check-file-that-a-file-association-exists-before-atte/6087057#6087057][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086973/how-can-i-programmatically-check-file-that-a-file-association-exists-before-atte/6087057#6087057

Comment: Thanks for the links you provided, would it be better to set a PDF Reader as prerequisites?(I'am using clickonce)

Comment: Even if a program registers for PDF files, it may not support being hosted in a webbrowser control. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227720/how-can-i-support-in-browser-display-of-a-pdf-file-in-internet-explorer-64-bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from whether it is useful to know or not, you could probable check the following registry key:

`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/pdf`

This will have an entry `CLSID`, which points to the class ID of the default application.

If the registry key or `CLSID` value is not present, then the MIME type is unknown, or there is no default application to handle the MIME type `application/pdf` files.

Comment: How to use this line in the C# for checking?

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: This approach has a catch, though: Windows 10 comes with Edge that opens PDF by default (as long as you have no N version of Windows 10, where it simply doesn't work). Edge is not registered as CLSID for application/pdf

Answer (score 2):

You can query the registry directly but the recommended solution is to use the [IQueryAssociations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb761400%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface to see if there is a program registered to open pdf's. An example can be found on [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shlwapi.AssocQueryString).

Answer (score 0):

C# implementation of the approach suggested by John Willemse (won't recognize Edge as default viewer on non-N version of Windows 10) :

```
    private bool CanOpenPDFFiles
    {
        get
        {
            bool CLSIDpresent = false;

            try
            {
                using (Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey applicationPDF = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"MIME\Database\Content Type\application/pdf"))
                {
                    if (applicationPDF != null)
                    {
                        var CLSID = applicationPDF.GetValue("CLSID");
                        if (CLSID != null)
                        {
                            CLSIDpresent = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

            return CLSIDpresent;
        }
    }
```