# Adobe PDF Reader ActiveX control 64 bit

Tags: c++, mfc, activex

I have problem with Adobe Reader ActiveX Control in MFC application. I'm working on big project, which is now refactored to 64 bit. And there is used this ActiveX control, which is only 32 bit. So it doesn't work and it crashes.

I have googled a lot, but I haven't found anything helpful. Don't you know, if there is some way, how to run this control in 64bit application or if there is some alternative?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152449/32-bit-activex-control-in-a-64-bit-net-app

Comment: Sorry, but I can't create other process.

Comment: Even if you could, it's would still be problematic by the sounds of it.  Can you run the 64 bit process in 32-bit mode?  that sort of defeats the purpose of porting it to 64-bit in the first place.

Comment: That said, there are 3rd party PDF viewers that could be used in a 64-bit environment, so these might be potential replacements for the Adobe one.

Comment: And don't you know any of them?

Comment: There is the Telerik one, http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#PdfViewer/FirstLook

Comment: I don't get it. Don't you have some link to info about it, not usage? And I'm not developing in .Net, but C++ / MFC.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10284/discussion-between-peskygnat-and-zacharmarz)